# Write new value of a key in an already defined JSON file

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON file of every user in my database. I want to change the value of a key from `true` to `false` on an action. How can I write it in  the file? Below is the JSON file:

```
{
  "name": "hi",
  "email": "hi@mail.com",
  "secFactorType": "microsoftTotpAuth",
  "loginid": "9867033239",
  "timezone": "+5.5",
  "workStartHours": "0900",
  "workEndHours": "1700",
  "ifRegenerateQR": true
}
```

I want to change the value of `ifRegenerateQR` to `false` in file.

```
JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(userInfoFile)).ifRegenerateQR = false;
```

This is not writing in the file. How do I use `fs.writeFile()` to write changes to file?

Comment: There are three different concepts involved in your problem: some data structure, a JSON that has been generated from the data structure, a file where the JSON is stored. Take them one at a time: read the text from file (use `fs.readFileSync()`), parse it as JSON to get back the data structure (use `JSON.parse()`), modify the data structure(`data.ifRegenerateQR = false`), generate another JSON from it (use `JSON.stringify()`) and write that JSON back into the file (use [`fs.writeFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options)).

Answer (score 2):

Read file and store in JS object.

```
const obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(userInfoFile));
```

Change whatever you want to change.

```
obj.ifRegenerateQR = false;
```

Write obj back to file.

```
fs.writeFile(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: [`fs.writeFile()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) is asynchronous. It returns immediately, postponing the actual writing. You need to pass it a callback function that it invokes when the writing is complete. Better use [`fs.writeFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options); it returns after the data has been written to file.

Comment: Yes fs.writeFileSync is better to use